# Django url pk + slug page not found

Tags: python, django, url, slug

I'm using django allauth for user authentication and so far I have been able to display user's page like this: account/1/trial/, where 1 is the pk number and trial is the username(unique), or like this: account/1/. In both cases everything works fine, but if I want to show only the username (account/trial/) in the url than I can't load the profile (accounts/profile/) page for the logged in user(404). Probably my profile function is wrong, how can I correct it so that the page will load normally as if using pk in urls.

urls:

```
(r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$", DetailView.as_view(context_object_name='detail',slug_field = "username",model=User,template_name='account/user_detail.html'), name='detail_view'), #if I use this url the page loads correclty

(r"^(?P<pk>\d+)/$", DetailView.as_view(context_object_name='detail',slug_field = "username",model=User,template_name='account/user_detail.html'), name='detail_view'), # also with this url it works

(r"^(?P<slug>[\w.@+-]+)/$", DetailView.as_view(context_object_name='detail',slug_field = "username",model=User,template_name='account/user_detail.html'), name='detail_view'), #if I use only the slug the page does not load.

(r"^profile/$", views.profile, name="profile_view"), #this is the profile page url
```

and the profile page view:

```
def profile(request):
    return render_to_response("account/profile.html",locals(),context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Comment: for starters, move the target `profile/$` above the slug pattern match

Answer (score 0):

The string "profile" matches the regex for the slug-only username view, and since Django matches URLs in order, a request for the URL "profile/" will always go to that view instead. The simple solution is to move the profile URL above the other one.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I should have thought of that immediately... anyways thanks for the fast solution